# What is the difference between Power Apps Plan and Power Apps Trial License?

Tags: admin, powerapps

I am researching how to create environments in Power Platform.  I notice that someone would have to visit license admin center for assigning licenses to users before trial environments can be created.

Here is the list of plans in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/create-environment#who-can-create-environments:

[image]

What is the difference between **Power Apps plan** and **Power Apps trial**?  Does Power Apps plan include an ability to create trial environments?

Does **Power Apps trial** actually expire 90 days and the user cannot create trial environments after 90 days?

What I really would like to know is what licenses are assigned to admins who, in turn, will assign trial environments to users?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link to know the latest policies about licenseing a power apps. you can go through the description given in the plan's card. it will allow you to choose best option for your specific solution.
[Power apps plans and licensing](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several licenses available for power apps like Per app plan,
Per user plan per app plan.

**Per app plan:**
Run one app or portal per user, stacking licenses for access to each additional as their needs change.

**Per user plan:**
Run unlimited apps and portals per user for one flat monthly rate.

**Per app plan:**
Use an Azure subscription to pay per user based on the number of unique apps a user runs each month.

**and power apps trail license:**
You can explore all the Power Apps capabilities for free by signing up for a 30-day Power Apps trial plan. If you don't have any license for Power Apps, the trial plan provides temporary access to do the following activities:

Extend the capabilities of Office 365 (SharePoint Online, Teams, Excel, and more)
Create and run canvas apps that connect to Microsoft Data verse and a wide range of more than 200 other data sources, including premium connectors and on-premises data
Create and run model-driven apps
Create automated workflows with Power Automate
Create and manage environments and Data verse databases.

please mark this answer accepted if the answer satisfy your need :)